# PokerStars have banned the use of PokerTracker 4. Why?

Tags: online, poker-tools

I have had this software for a while and indeed used it during a complaint I had with PokerStars. Now when I run both together, a pop-up appears telling me it is banned and further use could result in my suspension.

What could their reasons be and what recourse do I have as I purchased the software in good faith?

Comment: At worst you could still import hands and use the database tools to study your play. It's surely just some HUD features that PS has issues with, right?

Comment: I contacted PokerStars but they wouldn't elaborate on why I had to stop using the version of the software I had.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically it's buyer beware as to what it works on, but I think it's just an update issue. I did a little research and found this...

https://www.pokertracker.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=58&t=59668

It states that Pokerstars changed their T&Cs and it affected old versions of the tracker. Updating should resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

They don't need any reasons.  The software is third party and affects the client by overlaying a HUD.  This is not something other users of PokerStars may have access to thus can be considered an unfair advantage.  They need to protect their players and their product.

You can continue using the product and risk being banned.  Or you can stop using the product and run no risk.

In regards to purchasing the product you have no option there as purchasing products like this always run a risk or them not working with the client you choose or for the same situation you ran into.

Edit:

Ad Toby stated it seems to be a temporary issue.  I did a little research as well and it seems PS changes their rules from time to time which makes older clients bannable.  When using a third party program make sure you stay in the HM forums and PS forums to stay up to date on the software and the rules.

Comment: They may not *state* their reasons but they will have them. I also run a suite of my own tools so if there is something specific they have issue with, then it is in their interest to make it clear, otherwise similarly technically minded people to myself can simply circumvent the policies.

Comment: @RobbieDee I think the main reason PT and HM were banned recently was due to automatic classification of players as (nit/rock,fish,abc/tag,maniac/gambler,etc) based on their VPIP and PFR stats. PokerStars made it against the rules to classify the players, but the stats can still be tracked. They also imposed a new limit on the number of colours a HUD can use (I think it's 4).

Comment: @RobbieDee I don't remember my source for this, but I remember reading about it recently.

Comment: @Paulpro Looking at the release notes of the new version, they mention that they were forced to stop collecting stats for hero-less hands. PokerStars has a feature where you can fold but still watch the rest of the hand until its conclusion. This would in part allow you to build up a hand history for other players which clearly isn't in the spirit of a personal poker tool.